# Stretching full body after upper body workout?

Tags: workout, stretching, splits

I include stretching into every workout - **after** the workout itself. Since I'm doing an upper-body (Upper Back, Chest, Shoulders) lower-body (Legs, Lower Back, Belly) split I got to a question, which I think can be answered pretty good on here:

Is it necessary to stretch my lower body after an upper-body workout?

I train both upper and lower body twice a week, stretching only the upper body on an upper-body day would cut like 10 minutes out, what would be quite nice.

Comment: Necessary? What do you mean by that? Nothing is necessary, all of this is your choice. You can only train biceps and never stretch if you so desire. Do you want to know if there are benefits to stretching muscles you did not train? What is your goal?

Comment: @Raditz_35 Okay sorry for the bad phrasing. My goal obviously is to incorpurate stretches after my workout, but I also would love to cut these 10 minutes of lower-body streches out of my upper-body workour and vice versa. So the question is, are there any significant drawbacks of cutting it out and only stretching the muscles you actually used that day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what would be quite nice

So do it then?
I'm confused on what's stopping you here, this is completely your choice you either stretch or you don't. Whatever you feel benefits you more:

1) Stretching + Potential flexibility/limbering up

2) Your spare 10 minutes

You only have two options pick or don't neither are necessary, you won't die if you stop stretching but you won't die without your ten minutes either.

Comment: I wouldn't mind stretching nor sparing 10 minutes. The point is,for example, imagine if stretching the lower body after an upper body workout is significantly less usefull or pretty much useless, why would I invest my time in it? So the point is finding out if it is pretty much useless or if it has the same benefits as stretching after a full body workout.

Comment: Yeah pretty much useless. occasionally you may use your lower body in upper body exercises as a base but not enough to cause muscle tension however stretching is good in a flexibility point of view in which will help your form on other exercises so not pointless but for your reasoning then yes pointless